# python GC - reference counting works only WHEN gc.collect()?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I understand Python GC works in two ways:
1) **Basic reference counting** - below "John" has reference count of zero when "name" set to "Tom"

```
name = "John"
name = "Tom" (Reference count zero for "John")
```

2) **Detect Circular References** (Islands of Isolation). "GC" works at **in-deterministic** time (or if you invoke gc.collect() which isn't recommended).

Now, My question is, for (1), when name set to "Tom", "John" isn't collected **immediately** as soon as name = "Tom" right? GC would just mark "John" as **un-reacheable** and thus ready for collection (Which will happen **later**).
My understanding correct? Thanks

Reference:
https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/
https://pythoninternal.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/the-garbage-collector/

Answer (score 4):

Close, but the key detail is off:  when a reference count falls to 0 in CPython, the then-unreferenced object is *immediately* collected.  This has nothing to do with the cyclic GC system.  Indeed, you can do `gc.disable()` to disable the cyclic GC system completely, and reference counting will continue to collect non-cyclic garbage all on its own.

You can see this yourself via, e.g.,

```
import gc
gc.disable()
i = 1
while True:
    xs = [i]
    i += 1
```

That runs forever, but memory use will remain steady.  That's because reference counting alone recycles the memory for the integer and the list created on each iteration.

Comment: Since Python uses non-standard representation for integers allowing for "big integers", would not the memory increase over time from that? Albeit, very very slowly.

Comment: @Dair: In theory. The heat death of the universe would occur before any meaningful memory consumption.

Comment: Yes, but not that you'll notice in your lifetime ;-)  That is, we'll be long dead by the time `i` even reaches 2**64