# When we disable garbage collector in python using gc.disable(), Why it still destroy objects?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
import gc

class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Object initialisation')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Performing clean-up activities')

gc.disable()
d = Demo()
d = None
time.sleep(5)
print('End of code')
```

When we disable garbage collector in python using gc.disable(), Why it still destroy objects?

Output : 
Object initialisation...
Performing clean-up activities
End of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the destructor called when the CPython garbage collector is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578098/why-is-the-destructor-called-when-the-cpython-garbage-collector-is-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Because when the object `d` is referenced to `None`, the following code,

```
def __del__(self):
    print('Performing clean-up activities')
```

which is actually a destructor, is called automatically. This causes the unreferenced object (which `d` now is) to be deleted.
so,it has nothing to do with gc.

Comment: gc.disable() - Disable automatic garbage collection. So ideally destructor should not be called.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578098/why-is-the-destructor-called-when-the-cpython-garbage-collector-is-disabled